# How do I set the Query string to something like "?yr=something"?

Tags: php, url, query-string

Right now, I have a menu bar using query string that looks like this

```
<div class="PhaseMenuColumn">
            <a href="?1910-to-1949" name="Preamble">1910 to 1949</a>
        </div>
```

And  when I click on the link, it looks like

"history/?1910-to-1949"

But I need to have this so in URL it looks like

"history/?yr=1910-to-1949"

How do you set up query string so it could return URL correctly

Comment: What's wrong with just clicking just after the `?` then type `y`, `r`, `=`?

Comment: Apparently it's not following standard coding. and after this menu I'm using bunch of if statements to check query. After this I have bunch of if statements like if ($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] == '1980-to-1990'). Wouldn't it be really inefficient if I add yr= to all of them?

Comment: Can you explain more ? why you need the "yr" parameter as it is not needed ?

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="PhaseMenuColumn">
    <a href="?yr=1910-to-1949" name="Preamble">1910 to 1949</a>
</div>
```